# workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin throws not a constructor error, v6.0.2

Tags: workbox

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.0.2/workbox-sw.js');


workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ url, request }) => {
    if (url.host === self.location.host && request.destination !== 'document') {
      return true;
    }
  },
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: CACHE_KEY,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
        statuses: [0, 200]
      })
    ]
  })
);
```

throw error： Uncaught TypeError: workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin is not a constructor.

But if I use new workbox.cacheableResponse.CacheableResponse({statuses: [0, 200]}), there is no error, but the plugin still not effect. (opaque response not store to cache evenif set the cacheable statuses with [0,200])

Answer (score 0):

new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin is the api for v4.0.3.
I use v6.0.2, but unfortunately the latest version of @types/cacheableResponse is v4.0.3.
The correct api is new workbox.cacheableResponse.CacheableResponsePlugin for v6.0.2